# Row operation to transform a matrix to a triangular one

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following square matrix to which I need to calculate it's determinant

A = \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & ...   & n \\
    1 & a+1 & 3 & ...   & n \\
    1 & 2 & a+1 & ...   & n \\
    . & . & . & ...   & . \\
    . & . & . & ...   & . \\
    . & . & . & ...   & . \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & ...   & a+1 \\
    \end{matrix}
I have a strong feeling that this matrix can be reduced with some row operations to a triangular matrix and then the determinant will be a simple product of the prime diagonal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ri = Ri - R1 for each i>=2
realized it as soon as I posted it.